# How can I convince OSX to switch audio devices when I insert or remove a USB headset?

Tags: macos, audio, usb

I would like for OSX to switch audio output devices when I insert a USB headset. It should switch to the headset on insertion, and switch back to Speakers when I remove the headset.

I can't seem to find a way within the Sound preferences to do this. Is there a program out there which can handle it for me?

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: This was posted 5.25 years ago. 10.6 at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [sound source](http://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) from Rogue Amoeba (its free)